# how to return table on ajax call in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC. I have a DropDown in index view and i want to show entire table basis on selected item from dropdown. I fire ajax on onChange function of dropdown using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlUser").change(function () {
            $("#ddl2").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("getState")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { id: $("#ddlUser").val() },
                success: function (city) {

                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('failed to retrieve' + ex);
                }
            })
        });
         return false;
     });
```

and i get data from database using this code

```
    public JsonResult getState(int id)
    {
        MvcDemo9Feb.Models.ModelData MD = new Models.ModelData(); //MD is object of model and dt is DataTable type property 
        MD.dt = obDB.getCity(id);//obDB is class and getCity is method of it that return datatable
        return Json(MD);
    }
```

here i don't know how to bind data of model object MD to table on view. Please suggest something

Comment: you can use jquery datatables plugin to show your data in table see link http://www.datatables.net/ or you can use jtable plugin http://www.jtable.org/

Comment: @FrebinFrancis i am not much clear with that sir

Comment: I doubt if `return Json()` will correctly convert typeof `DataTable`. Create a model containing the properties you want and populate a collection. Then return that so you can access the properties in the ajax success callback to build your html table

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sir i have created model with that properties i required and i am trying to return that but i am unable to figure out how to bind that model data in view on ajax success

Comment: Thats because of you are passing the `DataTable`, not the collection of your DataModel

Comment: @VMAtm so what should i do

Comment: @SumeetBiswas, Show the models your referring to. And are you returning one item or a collection of items?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  public class ModelData
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public DataTable dt { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am try to return datatable

Comment: You can't return typeof `DataTable`. You need to map the properties of each row to a view model containing the properties you want to display and then return a collection of the view model (and why are you still using datatables anyway?)